# MenuItem not setting visibility properly

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I get the menu item and then i try to set the visibility but the menu item is always shown. Can anyone see where I am making a mistake?

The menu item is not null and thus is allocated so thats not it.

```
 MenuItem done = menu.findItem(R.id.action_done);
    //animate the list view
    if (isListEditing) {
        done.setVisible(true);
        menuItem.setTitle(this.getString(R.string.EditKey));
        isListEditing = false;
        adapter.endEdit();
    } else {
        done.setVisible(false);
        menuItem.setTitle(this.getString(R.string.DoneKey));
        isListEditing = true;
        adapter.makeEditable();
    }
    this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

I get the menu reference here:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_test_results, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    return true;
}
```

Update:

I was under the impression that you had to invalidate the options menu after you made an edit. But that is what was cause the edits to not go through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()), what invalidateOptionsMenu() does is:

> Declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) method will be called the next time it needs to be displayed.

That means onCreateOptionsMenu will get called again, inflating your original menu layout, and thus discarding your previous changes to the menu items visibility.

The recommended approach to modify the menu content dynamically is to use [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)). So whenever you need to update menu items, you can call invalidateOptionsMenu(), and then inside onPrepareOptionsMenu, you set the menu items visibility.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for

```
this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Take that off and it should work fine.